# Is there anything similar to NFC tags which i can use as far as few meters

Tags: nfc, rfid

I am just trying to bring some idea for that i need something similar to NFC which can communicate to my device just like NFC but should be able to communicate between few meters.

I have seen several NFC tags but they just work at few centimeters which do not full fill my purpose.

Found something similar too - NearBytes; But still it is not helping me

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Can you describe your requirements more?  What type of devices are you talking about? What type of environment?  What is your price point for a solution?

Comment: I am talking about devices/Technology which can interact with my phone and it should be pretty small. I have seen NFC tags but they have limitation of short distance range. I do not want to use BLE tags which is already present in market. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what exactly you want to achieve with the communication. Also completely depends on what devices you have available.

On assuming no limitations what so ever, BLE (Bluetooth Low Enegery) may be a technology to consider. It also works with radio but with the range of a few meters rather than a few centimetres as restricted by NFC. However although the technologies in essence are based in the same way, they are implemented rather differently.

Here is an interesting article comparing the two technologies of NFC and BLE with focus of mobile payments:

[Mobile Payment Transactions: BLE and/or NFC?](http://ul-ts.com/downloads/whitepapers/finish/6-whitepapers/282-mobile-payment-transactions-ble-andor-nfc)

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I appreciate your response. I need something small and thin like NFC. May be RFID tags can help me. But i do not have much knowledge in this area. I am going to use this with my mobile device to develop an app.           Many Thanks, Kishan

Comment: general case rfid requires a reader and antenna system which can be compact or large depending on the application.  you might want to read http://blog.atlasrfidstore.com/rfid-vs-nfc